# Creating an unknown number of Nodes Java

Tags: java, nodes, dijkstra

I'm working on a program that implements Dijkstra's algorithm on a series of vertices and their edge weights input by a user.  I do not know how many vertices the user is going to input until they actually input data. (one of the first input values will be the total number of vertices) My problem is that I do not know how to create a Node for each vertex without hard coding something such as:

```
Vertex v1 = new Vertex("VERTEX INFO");
Vertex v2 = new Vertex("VERTEX INFO");
Vertex v3 = new Vertex("VERTEX INFO");
```

etc.

To be more specific, I am basing my code off of this example [here](http://en.literateprograms.org/index.php?title=Special%3aDownloadCode/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm_%28Java%29&oldid=15444). In the main method this code has its Vertex nodes hard coded.

This is what I'd written on obtaining user input on a previous attempt (it was discarded because I ran into issues down the line and started over)

```
    ArrayList leftPoints = new ArrayList();
ArrayList rightPoints = new ArrayList();
ArrayList weights = new ArrayList();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

String searchInput = input.nextLine();

    String[] searchCommand = searchInput.split(" ");
    for(int i = 0; i <searchCommand.length; i++){
        System.out.print(searchCommand[i] + " ");
    }

        searchInput = input.nextLine();
        int totalVertices = Integer.parseInt(searchInput);

        while (input.hasNextLine()){            
        searchInput = input.nextLine(); 
        searchCommand = searchInput.split(" ");             
        int x = Integer.parseInt(searchCommand[0]);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(searchCommand[1]);
        int weight = Integer.parseInt(searchCommand[2]);

        leftPoints.add(x);
        rightPoints.add(y);
        weights.add(weight);

        }

        int[] x = new int[leftPoints.size()];
        int[] y = new int[rightPoints.size()];
        int[] pathWeights = new int[weights.size()];

        for (int p = 0; p < x.length; p++){
            x[p] = ((Integer) leftPoints.get(p)).intValue();
            y[p] = ((Integer) rightPoints.get(p)).intValue();
            pathWeights[p] = ((Integer) weights.get(p)).intValue();
        }
```

I converted the arraylists to integer arrays for an attempt that did not work at all, but decided to leave in the code in case it may help me here

Comment: Why don't you try with an **array** of Vertex?

Comment: Can you post what you've written so far?  Sounds like you are having trouble creating the Vertices based on user input.  But without knowing what your user input mechanics look like, it's hard to offer any help

Answer (score 0):

Create the vertices as the user inputs them, and add them to a list.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
List<Vertex> vertexList = new LinkedList<>();

while(sc.hasNext()) {
    vertexList.add(createVertexFromString(sc.next());
}
```

`createVertexFromString` is a method you would write yourself, obviously.